# Which version of MSXML began to support parsing XML 1.1?

Tags: msxml, xml-1.1

If I use MSXML6.dll to parse XML 1.1, I will get this error:
0xC00CE57F

MSG_E_INVALID_VERSION

Invalid version number

XML 1.1 was initially published on February 4, 2004. I'm surprised that MSXML6.dll can not parse it.

**The question:**
Does any MSXML4/5/6.dll support XML 1.1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no XML 1.1 with any MSXML version :(

As Microsoft states (see [data developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb291077.aspx) and [MSXML SDK Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760399.aspx)) MSXML is for applications that adhere to the XML 1.0 standard.

Comment: Microsoft instead of you ought to say sorry, shouldn't it? :)

Comment: You're perfectly right :) btw you can contact the xml team, I did years ago to place request for xslt 2.0, which they later decided to defer because of LINQ etc.