# How to get XSD version 1.1 in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, xsd-1.1

I have an XML Schema Document (XSD) that was using XSD version 1.0. That's all good but then I found out about some of the cool stuff *(assert, version control, etc.)* that was added in XSD version 1.1 and so I started updating my XSD.

Now I've just found out that the [MSXML2 libs don't support XSD version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451780/3451115) so I'm wondering if, for VBA, there are any other libraries that I can reference instead of MSXML?

---

FWIW these 'tutorials' are excellent: http://www.xfront.com/xml-schema-1-1/index.html

Comment: Well, you could write code in C#, wrap in a COM interface and make callable from VBA.

Comment: I just skip first line of xml file which has 1.1 and then it usually reads the rest of the file.

Comment: @SMeaden I would if I could, the learning curve for that would be steeper than I have time for right now

Comment: @jdweng wouldn't that prevent the new features from working?

Comment: So you want an XML parser released in 1999 to perform validation rules created in 2012...  I think you'll need a time machine : )

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Um, no... I was more hoping that there was an alternative XML library that is compatible with VBA and supports ver 1.1 which was first released (as I can tell in 2004: https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/ )...

Comment: There probably isn't any new feature in document.  Sometimes in the identification line there is other encoding like unicode, other wises, I've always been able to read in Net Library the entire file just by skipping the first line.

Comment: I'd look into Saxon, they stay up-to-date with, and even drive,  XML technologies.  MSXML was / is a great 1.0 parser, and suitable for most things, but hasn't had a meaninful update in 15 yrs.  XSD 1.1 -
(not xml 1.1) is from 2012  - https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/

Comment: Ah... that might be a source of confusion for me... I still very new to XML, **jdweng** I was thinking that the new XSD features would be neat (specifically the assert capability and that I could validate using XSD instead of code).  **WilliamW** I'll see if I can find a redistributable for Saxon... I already found something from Liquid XML (licence required) but I'm not sure if it would work in the way I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually asking about version 1.1 of the XML Schema specification (XSD), not version 1.1 of the XML specification. I've updated the title of your question accordingly.

There are currently three implementations of XSD 1.1: Saxon, Xerces, and Altova. Microsoft stopped implementing new W3C XML standards around 2004 and it seems unlikely they will ever do so, so you're dependent on third parties.

You could look at either the Saxon or Altova product lines for a solution here: I don't know what's needed to integrated into VBA. Saxon has a Saxon/C version which is a DLL with C-language APIs, and the Altova product (AFAIK) has COM interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for editing - what you're saying makes sense.  I'll see what I can find out re Altova, thanks

Comment: AND Saxon... :blush: